# tts с поддержкой русского языка

Tags: tts, android

Есть ли TTS (Text to Speach) библиотеки под Android c поддержкой русского языка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Обзор мобильных Text-To-Speech движков](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mobiledev/102199/):

- [Classic Text To Speech Engine](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.svox.classic&hl=ru)
- [eSpeak engine](http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/tutorial/tutorial.html)